# Javascript Splitting URL twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, url

Hi I've found a Javascript function I'm quite fond of which send the user to a page which depends on what they've entered into the text fields and want to implement into my new website. Only issue is this code only places one input fields text and I want 2!
Being quite new at this I could do with a little help understanding how to achieve this.

http://www.example.com/*input1*/*input2*.php

is what I want it to output.

Here is the code I' working with.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getURL(val){
base = 'http://www.example.com/';
exten = '.php';
var split = val.split(" ")
valup = split[0].toUpperCase();
valup2 = valup.replace(/ /, "");
location = base + valup2 + exten;
return false;}
</script>




<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return getURL(this.url.value)">

<label>
    <input type="text" id="suggest1" maxlength=4 size="4" style="color: #fff;" name="url" />
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="GO" />
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Using a code you don't understand is always a very bad idea. Don't skip the learning steps, do it properly and you will be able to modify this piece of code yourself. Don't ask others to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to get the value of both input, and it's best done before the submit button.

```
var formElem = document.getElementById('form1');
var input1 = document.getElementById('suggest1');
var input2 = document.getElementById('suggest2');
formElem.onsubmit = function() {
  location = 'http://example.com/' + input1.value + '/' + input2.value + '.php';
};
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot, much simpler than my code. I did need to add the return false; onto the end to make it work however. Cheers.